# How to correct set generic relation?

Tags: python, django

```
class A(models.Model):
    relation = GenericRelation('B')
    another_relation = GenericRelation('B')

class B(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

a = A()
b = B()
```

How to set connection so that I get b as result of a.another_relation.all()?

Answer (score 0):

From the [Django documentation `GenericRelation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#reverse-generic-relations) takes the class as the first arguments.

```
class B(models.Model):
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, blank=True, null=True)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    content = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

class A(models.Model):
    relation = GenericRelation(B)
    another_relation = GenericRelation(B)
```

You then should be able to use `a.another_relation.all()`.